# Application resource not available when using Unity bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, unity-container

I have the following resource defined in application resource

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="gridTextBox">
        <Setter Property="TextBox.Margin" Value="0,5,5,5"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And the resource is applied as usual on a textbox in main window

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Style="{StaticResource gridTextBox}"/>
```

The problem I am having is, that if I start the application via Unity bootstrapper, the application throws an XamlParseException on the textbox resource. But if I use a startupUri on app.xaml, then application loads as expected. My bootstrapper looks like this

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        var shell = new MainWindow();
        return shell;
    }
}
```

And my application startup is as follows

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new Bootstrapper().Run();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your App.xaml to this one:

```
<Application x:Class="UnityBootstrapperTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style x:Key="gridTextBox">
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.Margin" Value="0,5,5,5"/>
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! :) Do you maybe know why my version doesn't work, since AFAIK it should be the same?